# #pragma omp parallel num_threads is not working

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

```
    #include<omp.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    void main(int argc, int *argv[]){


   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
   {

    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Hello world from thread = %d \n",tid);
    if(tid == 0){
        int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("Number of threads = %d\n",nthreads);
    }
   }

  }
```

I am learning OpenMP and I don't understand why it executes only one thread when I have specified the number of threads 3?
The program ouptut:

```
   Hello world from thread = 0
   Number of threads = 1
```

Comment: You may have compiled it in a wrong way. In `gcc` for example, if you compile and link separately be sure to have `-fopenmp` for linking _and_ compiling. It should be similar for other compilers as well.

Comment: How did you compile this?  If it was in Visual Studio, you will have to [explicitly enable OpenMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515276/openmp-is-not-creating-threads).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile your program with `-fopenmp`.

```
g++ a.cc -fopenmp
```

Answer (score 3):

In VisualStudio just switch on OMP. You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fw509c3b(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 1):

omp_get_num_threads() returns the total number of threads being used

omp_get_thread_num() returns the current thread ID

You should use the former one